# How to use saved variable values outside of gatling scenario in scala file

Tags: scala, vector, gatling

One of gatling get request is giving multiple string values and I am saving them using saveAs like this:

```
val scn = scenario("ReadLogs")
        .exec(http("logEvent")
        .get("""/xyz/abc""")
        .check(jsonPath("$.data[*].message").findAll.saveAs("mList")))

/* My scala code to achieve some requirements*/
```

I can see in log that "mList" is a vector which have my required string messages. I want to process those messages in my scala code. How to do that in simple way? I think if i can use "mList" variable outside scn scenario than things will move fine so i'll put this question more specific. How can i use "mList" variable in my scala code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coding the process logic in a separate execution step, and make sure it is executed after the data is fetched.

```
val fetchLogs = exec(
  http("logEvent")
    .get("""/xyz/abc""")
    .check(jsonPath("$.data[*].message")
    .findAll
    .saveAs("mList")
)

val processLogs = exec { s: Session =>
    val mList = s("mList").as[Seq[Any]]
    val result = ...
    s.set("processResult", result)
}

val scn = scenario("ReadLogs").exec(
  fetchLogs,
  processLogs
)
```

Update: Save the data for later process

```
var mList: Seq[String] = _    

val fetchLogs = exec(
  http("logEvent")
    .get("""/xyz/abc""")
    .check(jsonPath("$.data[*].message")
    .findAll
    .transform { v => mList = v; v } // save the data
    .saveAs("mList")
)

val scn = scenario("ReadLogs").exec(fetchLogs)

after {
  // Process the data here. It will be executed when the simulation is finished.
}
```

Comment: I don't want to write process logic in another Gatling dependent function (as you suggested to write exec of processLogs). I want a independent vector variable whom i can use using any generic scala or java library. I intend to do many logical and file operations and for that i need values of "mList" in a variable (like a global variable). How can we do that?

Comment: You can do that in an 'after' block. See the update above.

Comment: Yes, This updated answer worked very well. Thanks. One additional question: What is the mean of "v" in saving operation? If i want to save Int than what to use?

Comment: The transform operation transforms the result of find operation. It is well documented in http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/cheat-sheet.html

Comment: I am using above fetchLogs part in loop where i am changing get parameter dynamically and every time new response comes. I need to append that string list to previous one. Gatling request failing with error "transform.findAll.exists failed, could not extract: transform crashed: null" when i tried below code: `exec(
  http("logEvent")
    .get("""/xyz/abc""")
    .check(jsonPath("$.data[*].message")
    .findAll
    .transform { v => mList = mList ++  v } // save the data
    .saveAs("mList1")
) `    Why? How to do this than?

Comment: It seems there is not always some data which can be extracted with the jsonPath expression. Maybe you should check whether the request is succeeded with a status code of 200, .check( status is 200, jsonPath("$.data[*].message") ...)

Comment: okay so i am making sure that every request should pass using ".check(status.in(200 to 201))". All requests are passing this check. Now how to append every new response to mList? '.transform { v => mList = mList ++ v }' is failing as mentioned above. What is wrong?