# How do I correctly correlate a SAML header response in Gatling

Tags: saml, correlation, gatling

I am looking to automate a performance test containing SAML authenticated logins.

The tool I chose for the job is Gatling but I am fairly new to this tool.

Now I run into the issue that my script will not fetch the SAML response from the response header.

```
    .exec(http("request_6")
        .post("/isam/sps/AD_Europe_SAM_SP/saml20/login")
        .headers(headers_6)
        .check(headerRegex("SAMLResponse", "SAMLResponse=(.*)").saveAs("saml_response"))
        .formParam("RelayState", "uuide0a0e23c-0168-1aea-bfd3-b405d391f0ea")
        .formParam("SAMLResponse", Seq("""${saml_response}""").mkString))
```

I was hoping this would do the job and fetch the SAMLResponse from the header.
But all it returns is the following error:

request_6: Failed to build request: No attribute named 'saml_response' is defined.

The SAML response I am trying to correlate is located in the form-data section of the header.

If anyone can help me figure out how to capture this header value, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: So just to be sure. Does your script fail at `saveAs` or at using the `saml_response` as a form param?

Comment: Right now it seems the error is about the use of the varaible saml_response, but I have no idea how to print the value that is or isn't extracted by the .check so I can verify if that has worked.

Comment: Check if this may solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250233/how-to-use-saved-variable-values-outside-of-gatling-scenario-in-scala-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I was looking for the SAML response in the wrong request (POST)
Instead of the intended request (GET)

When I added the extract line of code:

```
.check(headerRegex("SAMLResponse", "SAMLResponse=(.*)").saveAs("saml_response"))
```

To the correct response (The GET request) the issue was solved.